# Hyperledger Fabric Peer 2 Peer- error in channel start up

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using Hyperledger Fabric code base on GitHub. When I am following all the steps manually from generating certificates to starting the network through cli container I get the below error when I execute

`peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.example.com-cert.pem`

I even did
`export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD`
but but I am still getting the below errors:

`2017-06-15 19:35:37.332 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 001 intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/p‌​eerOrganizations/org‌​1.example.com/users/‌​Admin@org1.example.c‌​om/msp/intermediatec‌​erts]. Skipping.: [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/pe‌​erOrganizations/org1‌​.example.com/users/A‌​dmin@org1.example.co‌​m/msp/intermediatece‌​rts: no such file or directory]`

`2017-06-15 19:35:37.332 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 002 crls folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/p‌​eerOrganizations/org‌​1.example.com/users/‌​Admin@org1.example.c‌​om/msp/intermediatec‌​erts]. Skipping.: [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/pe‌​erOrganizations/org1‌​.example.com/users/A‌​dmin@org1.example.co‌​m/msp/crls: no such file or directory]`

`2017-06-15 19:35:37.333 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 003 MSP configuration file not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/p‌​eerOrganizations/org‌​1.example.com/users/‌​Admin@org1.example.c‌​om/msp/config.yaml]: [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/pe‌​erOrganizations/org1‌​.example.com/users/A‌​dmin@org1.example.co‌​m/msp/config.yaml: no such file or directory]`

And when I try to run it through the automated script provided in ./network.sh up I get the following error:

`2017-06-15 20:18:45.664 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 006 Failed to dial orderer.example.com:7050: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid"; please retry.Error: Error connecting due to  rpc error: code = Internal desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all note, that messages you are getting here

> 2017-06-15 19:35:37.332 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 002 crls folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/p‌​eerOrganizations/org‌​1.example.com/users/‌​Admin@org1.example.c‌​om/msp/intermediatec‌​erts]. Skipping.: [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/pe‌​erOrganizations/org1‌​.example.com/users/A‌​dmin@org1.example.co‌​m/msp/crls: no such file or directory]

They are not error messages and this is fine.

Next, note that

> export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD

is relevant in context of `configtxgen` tool and has no meaning while executing peer cli commands.

Not, sure what exactly you are trying to do with `network.sh` script, as its primary goal simply to run end-to-end test, with two orgs having two peers each, install and instantiate chaicode, issue transactions and query for results asserting the expected outcome.

Comment: I am referring
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?cm_mc_uid=64108713483714975446507&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1497559454&cm_mc_sid_52640000=1497559454
to create and start the network so that I can query or invoke transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why happens that error. The execution of the network.sh script should create a network without any problem. Would you try to "Run the tools" manually?

Answer (score 0):

removing and restarting the docker containers fixed it for me, there may be stale certificates from an old install like mine had.